# html5 video won't display on safari but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, safari, html5-video

I have a video slider on my page. here is the site http://shekleung.com/projects.html
The code work perfectly on chrome and ios safari but not desktop. On inspecting the site on safari, the video is present on the page in the html and even highlights blue where it's suppose to be. I know the slider is work because the text element changes depending the film being displayed. I'm confused at how this doesn't display at all in safari. I can only probably suspect the size being not right? I'm using vanilla js and css to create the slider. It display well and the slider work even on iphone.

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/mobile.css' />
   <title>Shek Leung</title>
</head>

<body class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
   <section class="projects-container">
      <nav>
         <div class="proj__nav">
            <a href="#archiveFilms" data-tab-target="#archiveFilms" class="archiveFilms active-proj">Archive Films</a>
            <a href="#soundDY" data-tab-target="#soundDY" class="dearYou link-color">Sound: Dear You</a>
            <a href="#soundDS" data-tab-target="#soundDS" class="directorSt link-color">Sound: Final Director's
               Statement</a>
         </div>
         <a href="/index.html" class="proj__back link-color">Back</a>
      </nav>

      <main class="projects-main">
         <div id="archiveFilms">
            <div class="carousel">
               <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left">←</button>
               <div class="carousel__track-container">
                  <ul class="carousel__track">
                     <li class="carousel__slide current-slide">

                        <video class="carousel__video" id="blue" src="/img/Projects/blue-research-film.mp4"
                           preload="metadata"></video>
                     </li>
                     <li class="carousel__slide">

                        <video id="lvproj" class="carousel__video"
                           src="/img/Projects/lv-project.mp4" preload="metadata"></video>
                     </li>
                     <li class="carousel__slide">

                        <video id="walking" class="carousel__video"
                           src="/img/Projects/we-create-paths-by-walking.mp4" preload="metadata"></video>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">→</button>

               <div class="vid-nav">
                  <p class="carousel__slide-text">BLUE → Research Film (2015)</p>
                  <span class="play">▶</span>
                  <span class="audio">♩</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="soundDY">
            <div class="container__sound">
               <div class="container__audio">
                  <p class="container__header">"Dear You" Sound (2018)</p>
                  <audio controls>
                     <source src="/img/Projects/Dear You (2018).mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                  </audio>
               </div>
               <div class="container__credit">
                  <p>Collaboration for BA Collection→<br><br>
                     Concept by Samson Leung<br>
                     Music composed by Zacharias Wolfe<br>
                     <br>Performed by the following:
                     <br><br>Alto Saxophone solo - Theo Hillborg
                     <br>Violins - Abel Puustinen, Pierpaolo Casamassima, Claire Edwards,
                     Elisabeth Turmo, Ismael Jarmouni Gómez & Esther Park
                     <br>Viola - Georgie Davis & Tiffany Cheng
                     <br>Cello - Shizuku Tatsuno & Meera Priyanka Raja
                     <br>Bass - Peter Farthing
                     <br>Studio engineer and mix - Luke Knott
                     <br>Final mix and editing - Oliver Buckland</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="soundDS">
            <div class="container__sound">
               <div class="container__audio">
                  <p class="container__header">“Final Director's Statement Sound" (2020)
                  </p>
                  <audio controls>
                     <source src="/img/Projects/Final Director's Statement (2020).mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                  </audio>
               </div>
               <div class="container__credit">
                  <p>Collaboration for MA Collection→<br><br>
                     Concept by Samson Leung<br>
                     Music composed by Zacharias Wolfe<br>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
   </section>
   <script src="js/projects.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
const projTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.proj__nav a');
const directorSt = document.querySelector('.directorSt');
const dearYou = document.querySelector('.dearYou');
const archiveFilms = document.querySelector('.archiveFilms')
const pageAudios = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('audio'));
const pageVideos = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('video'));
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);


projTabs.forEach(tab => {
   tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
      pageAudios.forEach(a => {
         if (!a.paused) {
            a.pause();
         } else {}
      })
      pageVideos.forEach(v => {
         if(!v.isPaused) {
            v.pause();
         } else {}
      })
   })
})

if (!archiveFilms) {} else {
   archiveFilms.addEventListener('click', () => {
      projTabs.forEach(tab => {
         tab.classList.remove('active-proj');
         tab.classList.add('link-color');
         archiveFilms.classList.remove('link-color');
         archiveFilms.classList.add('active-proj');
      })
   })
}

if (!dearYou) {} else {
   dearYou.addEventListener('click', () => {
      projTabs.forEach(tab => {
         tab.classList.remove('active-proj');
         tab.classList.add('link-color');
         dearYou.classList.remove('link-color');
         dearYou.classList.add('active-proj');
      })
   })
}
if (!directorSt) {} else {
   directorSt.addEventListener('click', () => {
      projTabs.forEach(tab => {
         tab.classList.remove('active-proj');
         tab.classList.add('link-color');
         directorSt.classList.remove('link-color');
         directorSt.classList.add('active-proj')
      })
   })
}

const track = document.querySelector('.carousel__track');
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel__button--right')
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel__button--left');
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
const videoText = document.querySelector(".carousel__slide-text");
const carouselVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel__video');
const blue = document.querySelector('#blue');
const lvProj = document.querySelector('#lvproj');
const walking = document.querySelector('#walking');
const audio = document.querySelector('.vid-nav .audio');
const play = document.querySelector('.play');


const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
   slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + "px";
}
slides.forEach(setSlidePosition);


const moveToSlide = (track, currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
   track.style.transform = "translateX(-" + targetSlide.style.left + ")";
   currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
   targetSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
   if (targetSlide === slides[1]) {
      videoText.innerHTML = "LV Project → Hologram Presentation (2016) ";
      nextBtn.style.display = "block";
      prevBtn.style.display = "block";

   } else if (targetSlide === slides[2]) {
      videoText.innerHTML = "We Create Paths By Walking (2016)";
      nextBtn.style.display = "none";
      prevBtn.style.display = "block";

   } else if (targetSlide === slides[0]) {
      videoText.innerHTML = "BLUE → Research Film (2015)";
      nextBtn.style.display = "block";
      prevBtn.style.display = "none";
   }
}


prevBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
   const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
   const prevSlide = currentSlide.previousElementSibling;
   moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, prevSlide);
   carouselVideos.forEach(v => {
      if (!v.paused) {
         v.pause();
         audio.classList.remove('blinking');
         play.innerHTML = "▶";
      };
   })

})


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
   const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
   const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
   moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
   carouselVideos.forEach(v => {
      if (!v.paused) {
         v.pause();
         audio.classList.remove('blinking');
         play.innerHTML = "▶";
      };
   })
})
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
   audio.classList.add('blinking');
   if (slides[0].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolSwitch(blue)
   } else if (slides[1].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolSwitch(lvProj)
   } else if (slides[2].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolSwitch(walking);
   }
})


function symbolSwitch(element) {

   if (element.paused) {
      element.play();
      play.innerHTML = "||"
      if (element.muted) {
         audio.classList.remove('blinking');
      }
   } else {
      element.pause();
      play.innerHTML = "▶";
      audio.classList.remove('blinking');
   }

}
audio.addEventListener('click', () => {

   if (slides[0].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolBlink(blue)

   } else if (slides[1].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolBlink(lvProj)
   } else if (slides[2].classList.contains('current-slide')) {
      symbolBlink(walking)
   }
})


function symbolBlink(element) {
   if (element.muted === true && (!element.paused)) {
      element.muted = false;
      audio.classList.add('blinking');
   } else {
      element.muted = true;
      audio.classList.remove('blinking');

   }
}

function smoothScroll(target, duration) {
   var target = document.querySelector(target);
   var targetPos = target.offsetLeft;
   var startPos = window.pageXOffset
   var distance = targetPos - startPos;
   var startTime = null; // keeps track of time

   function animation(currentTime) {
      if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
      var timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
      var run = easeOut(timeElapsed, startPos, distance, duration);
      window.scrollTo(run, 0);
      if (timeElapsed < duration) {
         requestAnimationFrame(animation);
      }
   }

   function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
      t /= d;
      return -c * t * (t - 2) + b;
   };

   requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)").matches) {
   carouselVideos.forEach(v => {
      v.controls = true;
   })
} else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try renaming you video so it doesn't have all the spaces in the name? I tried it in the browser debugging mode and it seemed to work!

Comment: hmm I updated the code in the server but it doesn't seem to work - i have edited the code above to show the change too

Comment: so you changed the name in the browser debug tools and the video displayed??

Answer (score 0):

Okay this was solved because-

1. apple requires "playinline" attribute on html 5 video element
2. IMPORTANTLY - we have to provide a background image ('poster' property) for when video is not played by user. Chrome does this automatically - generates a frame but Safari requires this in the video tag or it appears blank.